# google-cloud-build PyPi 400 errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am currently receiving 400 errors when invoking the `list_builds()` method (seen here: https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudbuild/latest/gapic/v1/api.html?highlight=list_builds#google.cloud.devtools.cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient.list_builds)

The following command works using gcloud:

`gcloud builds list --filter="status=FAILURE"`

However, the following API call returns `google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Error processing filter expression`

```
for element in client.list_builds("REDACTED", filter_="status=FAILURE"):
    # process element
    pass
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something very obvious and simple here but I can't exactly figure out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to pass in the filter string to the API call includes using double apostrophes around the actual text like so:

`filter_='status="FAILURE"'`

Unsure of whether or not this will be changed in the future, but this is the same behavior for passing it in via the REST API here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/list

e.g specifiying `status=FAILURE` will fail, but `status="FAILURE"` returns a 200 response.

Comment: WHY does GCP insist upon these ridiculous constructs? Thanks for sharing the solution, there's no way I would have guessed this format.

Comment: I think the Cloud Build API has some maturing to do, as I haven't seen other "filter" arguments in other services require this type of parameter sanitation from the user.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack O! So I'm just spitballing here, but the docs say that the Filter string is "The raw filter text to constrain the results."

When you filter a Cloud Build in the console, the "raw filter text" in the UI says `Status : Failed` - you could try:

`--filter="Status : Failed"`

`--filter="Status: Failed"`

`--filter="Status:Failed"`

Alternately, it *might* be the string in the URL, the formatting of which is too bananapants for Stack O's robots to handle, so I can't paste it here, but it starts with `f` and ends with `Failed`:

The key here is that you have an equal sign in your string, as well as `Failure` instead of `Failed` - changing one or both of those might do the trick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just to re-iterate, the gcloud command I showed does in fact work (and returns valid results). 

It's at the point that I try to make the equivalent API call using the google-cloud-build Python API client and pass in that same value for the filter_ variable, I am given a 400 error; the other variants you suggested seem to not work for both the API call as well as the gcloud command filter.

Comment: Welp, it was worth a shot. I noticed on this page - https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results - that the output from the sample `describe` command is "status: SUCCESS" - which is what led me to suggest the colon rather than the equal sign. Have you experimented with all caps yet? GCP isn't horrible but it has some pretttty rough edges.

Comment: OH, UGGH, AND! That same page shows two types of build status strings: FAILED and FAILURE. Super duper. Please do update us when you find the answer, my curiosity is piqued now.

Comment: After enabling the -log-http flag on the gcloud command I was able to trace the HTTP request for the builds list endpoint, it turns out I had to pass in the filter in the API call exactly like so: ```filter_='status="FAILURE"'```. A little frustrating, to say the least (given that I wouldn't have guessed to use both single and double apostrophes in my string assignments)

Comment: Hi! Given that you found how to solve your issue, could you add your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: If you have not resolved your issue, please indicate what is your current error.

Comment: My issue has in fact been resolved and I've posted a follow up comment; I will mark it as my accepted solution as soon as the option becomes available. Thank you!